# Accessing the AST used for building a symtable

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree, symbol-table

In my program I need both the [symtable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/symtable.html) and the [AST](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/ast.html) of a piece of code.

Currently I'm doing:

```
import ast
import symtable

code = 'foo'
ast.parse(code)
symtable.symtable(code, '?', 'exec')
```

But because `symtable()` creates an AST itself, I'm actually creating the AST twice. And since my code needs to run fast, I'd rather use the AST that was already created for the symtable than creating a second one, which takes extra time.

So, is there a way to access the AST that was built for generating the symtable? In other words, can I have both an AST and a symtable for the same code without creating the AST twice?

Comment: seems there's no current way.  `symtable` does not expose the ast object it compiles (only using it generate the output symtable object)

Comment: @AnthonySottile Any idea if I could maybe use some C extension magic to get a reference to the AST object?

Comment: The ast object is only used as a temporary in the `symtable` construction: [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L1142-L1143) (I believe the `arena` holds the ast object).

Comment: so probably not :(

Comment: @AnthonySottile Anyway, thanks for digging!